# How do I generate an ID that is garunteed to be unique?

Tags: c#

I need to garuntee the uniqueness of an ID. Even if there's a 1 in 1 trillion chance of there being a dupe, I cannot use it.

But I don't really feel like going to the ends of the earth to find a solution either. I have spent some time looking into this, and everything I have found to date isn't able to garuntee me a unique ID.

So I thought I would use something very simple, like this:

```
    public static string GenerateItemID()
    {
        string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(), 
            month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString(), 
            day = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString(), 
            hour = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString(), 
            minute = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString(), 
            second = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString(), 
            millisecond = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();

        return year + month + day + hour + minute + second + millisecond;
    }
```

My logic here is: each new UI that is generated can not possibly be the same as any of the previous ones. But then I wondered if it were possible for a PC to generate two or more of these ID's within the same millisecond? Naturally, I then looked in Intellisense for a Nanosecond property, but it doesn't exist.

How can I generate an ID that is **garunteed** to be unique?

Comment: Where did you manage to buy a processor that never produces an incorrect result?

Answer (score 4):

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

I believe this will create a fairly unique id.

Comment: Are GUID's _garunteed_ to _always_ be unique? I have read that there is still some margin for duplication.

Comment: I imagine there is 1 in a quadrillion chance or so. You could use a 'while' and say while (id is not unique) generate new guid?

Comment: Guids will most likely be sufficient, check out this article for additional information:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx

Comment: You could just add a random 8 digit number after your milliseconds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-alphanumeric-strings-in-c

Comment: Then add logic to retry to generate a new GUID should the one you try to insert fail...

Comment: @TRose I was just thinking that! lol

Comment: @SE13013 added a link to an example.

Comment: @SE13013 No, they aren't (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30919505/613130)... But they are guaranteed to be statistically unique (in the sense that the probability of a collision is so much low to be *truly* low...)

Answer (score 2):

Let use GUID.

Refer here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this help.